# Strapi:google providers issue

Tags: strapi

I have a question regarding Providers.
I'm using Strapi in the docker with Nginx reverse proxy and I set  up google provider and service.js I added URL: env("", "https://my-link.com/api"),
in the beginning, everything was working fine till I clear the browser cache. Now I'm getting an error
`Grant Missing session or misconfigured provider`
so when I call `/connect/google/callback` its fail with 302

On the Strapi website, I found this but not much clear how to debug the issue

```
Grant: missing session or misconfigured provider: It may be due to many things.
The redirect URL can't be built: Make sure you have set the backend URL in config/server.js: Setting up the server URL
A session/cookie/cache problem: You can try again in a private tab.
The incorrect use of a domain with ngrok: Check your urls and make sure that you use the ngrok URL instead of http://localhost:1337. Don't forget to check the backend url set in the example app at src/config.js.
```

Thanks in advance.